How to use MySQL `WHERE` statement using `@StartDate` & `@EndDate` on looker studio so the data can be dynamically loaded based on date range control
How to use MySQL WHERE statement using @StartDate and @EndDate on looker studio so the query can be dynamically loaded from the MySQL database based on the Looker Studio's 'Date Range Control Properties'?
After using this query i can't see the @StartDate and @EndDate at the "Date Range Dimension" inside the 'Setup' tab.
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE DATE(xxx.time_stamp) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT ...

I'm trying to find the documentation related to this issue but i can't find it

@StartDate and @EndDate in this query are two MySQL user-defined variables. You must SET their values before the query execution, or in separate subquery in FROM clause. If a Watch tab exists in your studio then add these variables into and look for their values.

A sample: https://dbfiddle.uk/vFMpWXIU

I've tried it but it's not working, is it because i'm not using BigQuery?

I'm afraid that's not possible with MySQL, only with BigQuery.
I think you refer to the variables @DS_START_DATE and @DS_END_DATE, which can be used in a custom query when connecting to BigQuery, like so
WHERE start_date > PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) 

But unfortunately that is not available for MySQL (neither is it for example for Snowflake, and I believe for any other third party data source).
To dynamically change the date on the charts you can just use a date range control (Add a control > Date range control)

The current state of my server on the office is not cloud based, using MySQL, so the only way to be able dynamically change the date to see the changes on chart is only without using WHERE statement? and date/date time on the SELECT statement is required to be able to use the data range control right?

No, the filter in the query is only to minimize the data queried from the DB and is not actually needed. To dynamically change the date on the charts you can just use a date range control (Add a control > Date range control).

Let me know if this answers your question - and if so, I'd appreciate if you "Accepted" this answer. Thanks!
